# How can I scaffold ReactJs with Laravel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I tried to installLlaravel and scaffold ReactJs.
I have a problem in running my react component.

The installation was fine and
Below is my first ReactJs component. However I cannot display the content of the react component.

**components/Example.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header">Example Component</div>

                            <div className="card-body">I'm an example component!</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

Here is the file welcome.blade, inside the body

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

It should display like this,

Example Component
I'm an example component!

Comment: Got any errors in your developer tools? Did you run `npm run dev`?

Comment: This problem was 3 months ago, and was resolved. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. install nodejs and npm
2. run `npm run dev` for development and `npm run prod` for production on your laravel root directory